# PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods implementations

Tags: swift, applepay

We have to add debit/credit cards from App to Apple Wallet

```
let config = PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration.init(encryptionScheme: PKEncryptionScheme.ECC_V2)
config?.cardholderName = "John"
config?.primaryAccountSuffix = "9999" //last 4 or 5digits of card
config?.localizedDescription = "This will add the card to Apple Pay";
config?.primaryAccountIdentifier = "test";
config?.paymentNetwork = PKPaymentNetwork(rawValue: "VISA");

guard let addPaymentPassVC = PKAddPaymentPassViewController.init(requestConfiguration: config!, delegate: self) else { return }
self.present(addPaymentPassVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


extension ViewController: PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate {
    func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, 
generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data], 
nonce: Data, 
nonceSignature: Data, 
completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void) {



    }

    func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, 
didFinishAdding pass: PKPaymentPass?, 
error: Error?) {

        print("didFinishAdding")

    }


}
```

What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think that first, you should check PassKit documentation from Apple to understand correctly how it works(https://developer.apple.com/wallet/). Then maybe this website could works for you: https://github.com/tschoffelen/php-pkpass

But you could not do anything until you speak directly with apple to give you their permission.